# Is there anyway to make canvas object auto snap align on Fabric.js

Tags: fabricjs

Im working on a project of building a editor, i am using the Fabric.js, but i don know how to make the canvas object auto align.

Is there any example of making canvas object auto align with another object like this?
image of snap example
[auto snap example from other site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vS3Ld.png)

link here:
[auto snap example site](http://namecardonline.com/eng/editor.aspx?action=content&template=10002-1-0-0#/modified)

Comment: I am still getting likes on my answer so I don't know why this is closed. I updated the Git repo, which had a security warning on it because apparently bootstrap used to be bad. The code is solid and still working. I am hoping to see this corrected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was working on the same thing. This seems to be a pretty common feature request so I thought I'd share what I worked out. It could use some refinement. For instance, I've noticed if you scale the red box, the scale is not applied and it doesn't align right. However, I think it demonstrates the basic principal well and you can elaborate on it to fit your needs.

(Note: 8/1/2017: Working to place a more comprehensive code base on GitHub. (https://github.com/JerrodV/FabricObjectAlignment) More Details Soon!)

You can view the fiddle [here][1]

Html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <canvas id="c" height="600" width="600" style="border:1px solid #c1c1c1;"></canvas>
    </div>
    </form>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/fabric.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/default.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
Def = {
    canvas: null,    
    rect: null,
    lines: {
        top: null, 
        left: null,
        right: null,
        bottom: null
    },
    init: function () {
        Def.canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

        Def.canvas.on('object:moving', Def.events.objectMoving);

        Def.canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            top: 100,
            left: 200,
            fill: 'black',
            selectable: false
        }));

        Def.canvas.add(new fabric.Rect({
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            top: 300,
            left: 100,
            fill: 'black',
            selectable: false
        }));        

        Def.rect = new fabric.Rect({
            height: 100,
            width: 100,
            top: 200,
            left: 250,
            fill: 'red'
        });

        Def.canvas.add(Def.rect);
    },
    events: {
        objectMoving: function (e) {
            //Get the object being manipulated
            var obj = e.target;

            //Set up an object representing its current position
            var curPos = {
                top: parseInt(obj.get('top')),
                left: parseInt(obj.get('left')),
                right: parseInt(obj.get('left') + obj.get('width')),
                bottom: parseInt(obj.get('top') + obj.get('height'))
            };

            //Set up an object that will let us be able to keep track of newly created lines
            var matches = {
                top: false,
                left: false,
                right: false,
                bottom: false
            }

            //Get the objects from the canvas
            var objects = Def.canvas.getObjects();

            //For each object
            for (var i in objects) {

                //If the object we are looing at is a line or the object being manipulated, skip it
                if (objects[i] === obj || objects[i].get('type') === 'line') { continue; }

                //Set up an object representing the position of the canvas object
                var objPos = {
                    top: parseInt(objects[i].get('top')),
                    left: parseInt(objects[i].get('left')),
                    right: parseInt(objects[i].get('left') + obj.get('width')),
                    bottom: parseInt(objects[i].get('top') + obj.get('height'))
                }

                //Look at all 4 sides of the object and see if the object being manipulated aligns with that side.

                //Top////////////////////////////////////
                if (Def.inRange(objPos.top, curPos.top)) {
                    //We match. If we don't already have aline on that side, add one.
                    if (!Def.lines.top) {
                        Def.drawLine('top', objPos.top);
                        //Keep track of the fact we found a match so we don't remove the line prematurely.
                        matches.top = true;
                        //Snap the object to the line
                        obj.set('top', objPos.top).setCoords();
                    }
                }               
                //Left////////////////////////////////////
                if (Def.inRange(objPos.left, curPos.left)) {
                    if (!Def.lines.left) {
                        Def.drawLine('left', objPos.left);                        
                        matches.left = true;
                        obj.set('left', objPos.left).setCoords();
                    }
                }                
                //Right////////////////////////////////////
                if (Def.inRange(objPos.right, curPos.right)) {
                    if (!Def.lines.right) {
                        Def.drawLine('right', objPos.right);                        
                        matches.right = true;                        
                        obj.set('left', objPos.right - objects[i].get('width')).setCoords();
                    }
                }                
                //Bottom////////////////////////////////////
                if (Def.inRange(objPos.bottom, curPos.bottom)) {
                    if (!Def.lines.bottom) {
                        Def.drawLine('bottom', objPos.bottom);                        
                        matches.bottom = true;
                        obj.set('top', objPos.bottom - objects[i].get('height')).setCoords();
                    }
                }

                //Look at the side we matched on. If we did not match, and we have a line, remove the line.
                for (var j in matches) {
                    var m = matches[j];
                    var line = Def.lines[j]; 
                    if (!m && line) {
                        Def.canvas.remove(line);
                        Def.lines[j] = null;
                    }

                }

            }
            Def.canvas.renderAll();
        }
    },
    drawLine: function (side, pos) {
        var ln = null
        switch (side) {
            case 'top':
                ln = new fabric.Line([Def.canvas.get('width'), 0, 0, 0], {
                    left: 0,
                    top: pos,
                    stroke: 'rgb(178, 207, 255)'
                });
                Def.lines.top = ln;
                break;
            case 'left':
                ln = new fabric.Line([0, Def.canvas.get('height'), 0, 0], {
                    left: pos,
                    top: 0,
                    stroke: 'rgb(178, 207, 255)'
                });
                Def.lines.left = ln;
                break;
            case 'right':
                ln = new fabric.Line([0, Def.canvas.get('height'), 0, 0], {
                    left: pos,
                    top: 0,
                    stroke: 'rgb(178, 207, 255)'
                });
                Def.lines.right = ln;
                break;
            case 'bottom':
                ln = new fabric.Line([Def.canvas.get('width'), 0, 0, 0], {
                    left: 0,
                    top: pos,
                    stroke: 'rgb(178, 207, 255)'
                });
                Def.lines.bottom = ln;
                break;
        }
        Def.canvas.add(ln).renderAll();
    },
    alignTolerance : 6,
    inRange: function (val1, val2) {
        if ((Math.max(val1, val2) - Math.min(val1, val2)) <= Def.alignTolerance) { return true; }        
        else { return false; }
    }
};

$(Def.init);
```

I hope you find this useful. Good Luck!
[1]: https://jsfiddle.net/cLy86rtd/

Comment: The people behind the library you built this script for really shouldn't matter at all. You can't just redact your answer like this. A lot of other people with hopefully closer to your standards precepts may still need this. StackOverflow doesn't do politics or social sciences, we only build a library of knowledge. The knowledge you kindly shared here doesn't harm, and thus should not get redacted.