# Creating "snapping centering lines" on fabric.js canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I'm interested in programmatically setting "center points" that I can have only appear when objects are crossing them but I'm not really sure where to begin.

Ideally, I'd have one horizontal line and 2 vertical lines appear when an object crosses any one of them, to help guide the user to center the object (only when selected/moving), instead of having to eyeball it. The object would snap to the line wherever it did cross it. (see image example):

[image]

The closest I've seen to anything like this [was this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37338183/is-there-anyway-to-make-canvas-object-auto-snap-align-on-fabric-js), which is similar but still very different.

Other notes:

- I am using fabric.js v 1.7.20

Comment: Are you still interesting in this? I've done it before and could offer some advice, but this question is 6 months old now.

Comment: @JonathanDumaine yes, very!

Comment: @JonathanDumaine Can you please offer your advice regarding this topic?